# I need specific table data for each users

Tags: mysql, database

I am doing my master thesis and I found unknown problem.

I make football simulator app

-> you can simulate alternative football future for all European leagues.

But I have a problem in MySQL database

-> at the beginning of game I need to give user whole data.

But after this, some data evolves (some players score goals, teams have points), but I need to store these data for each user separately (for example, some user have 2 seasons simulated and some 10 seasons -> both with completely different results).

Is there any more effective way than having separate tables for each user (because for example players table have more than 50,000 rows)?

Thanks!

Using PHP7,node.js backend,MySQL db.

Comment: Yes, you could have one table for all users.

Comment: I cannot, because for some users same player can have different number of goals scored for example. They all have different games, only some data stay same (player name, club name,...).

Comment: You might have one table which stores which simulation belongs to which user, and another table which stores the number of goals each player has scored in each simulation. Your question is a bit broad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can have one table for all users. Just seperate each user by `user_id` column.

```
create table seasion_with_users
(
    session_id
    user_id int,
    ....
    ....  
);
```

also If you have storage concern, I suggest you to mutate only changing rows.

Comment: without knowing table structure of the user how do I supposed to include column names?